# How do hygrometers work?

Tags: measurements, applied-physics

How does this [hygrometer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hygrometer) work? Please be clear.
[image]

I didn't understand this past on hygrometers in a physics textbook. Can someone elaborate?

Comment: What was your particular issue? Another description is here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hygrometer

Comment: This is completely different. It has ether, a hollow tube and other complications. Please explain the working of THIS hygrometer

Comment: No, this is  a chilled dew point hydrometer as described in the wiki link, albeit with a second reference device to facilitate more accurate comparison during dew point determination.

Comment: It is indeed possible to read your textbook image.

Comment: Ok.How does it work then?

Comment: You want me to cut and paste from wikiedia? What don;t you understand?

Answer (score 1):

[*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hygrometer) tells you. It looks like you are asking about wet-bulb vs. dry-bulb. The wet-bulb thermometer measures *dew point*, the temperature at which dew forms.

You know that a wet surface cools down due to evaporation.
That's why people sweat - to cool down.
You know that it's easier to cool down if the air is dry than if it's humid.

Technically speaking, the temperature you can cool down to is the dew point.
The more humidity there is, the higher the dew point is.
When the dew point reaches the dry-bulb temperature, you get fog.

The unit in the book just has another way to cool off one of the thermometers, by evaporating ether.

Comment: This is completely different. It has ether, a hollow tube and other complications. Please explain the working of THIS hygrometer

Comment: No, this is  a chilled dew point hydrometer as described in the wiki link, albeit with a second reference device to facilitate more accurate comparison during dew point determination.

Answer (score 1):

This is merely an analog of the chilled mirror dew-point hygrometer on that very same [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hygrometer) page. You would also easily get another fully detailed explanation right [*here*](http://gulpmatrix.com/how-regnaults-dew-point-hygrometer-works/) if you had Googled "Regnault's hygrometer", as it is called in your own textbook (top paragraph, third line). It is not completely different. I would humbly advise you to invest more effort (such as going through the full explanation slowly, step-by-step in your head) before posting a question asking for an explanation/elaboration. I believe everything you need is easily obtained via Google, Wikipedia, careful reading of your text and time spent thinking about it yourself. That being said, I hope the following helps:

The setup you have is merely two test tubes holding ether. Ether is an organic compound, a combination of alkyl and/or aryl groups connected by an oxygen atom that usually has very low boiling points and is highly volatile (you could have known this by googling "ether"). Each test tube also has two things in them; a thermometer and an open tube exposed to the air. $A$ is connected to the hollow stand but $B$ is not (notice the small line disconnecting test tube $B$).

The hollow stand (and by extension, test tube $A$) is connected to a tube which is connected to that vessel $E$. Vessel $E$ has water that slowly leaks out and pulls air through the tube, through the hollow stand and through test tube $A$, which then sucks air through the ether through the open tube (the thing next to the thermometer). This forces air through the ether in test tube $A$ and vaporises it, causing test tube $A$ to cool. When it has cooled enough, the silvered surface is clouded (because of water condensing on it). You notice when the clouding happens (you can compare the shiny-ness to test tube $B$), take the temperature reading and then you stop the leaking in vessel $E$.

Once the leaking stops, the ether that was vaporised starts to become liquid again and test tube $A$ rises in temperature. Once again, you watch for when the silvered surface of $A$ becomes as clear as the one on $B$ and take the temperature reading when that happens. Their average is what you should use for the dew-point temperature. The open tube in test tube $B$ is exposed to the atmosphere with no sucking or pulling of air. Thus, test tube $B$ will "normalise" to the temperature of the atmosphere and the surroundings. This whole thing gives you the dew-point temperature *of those particular surroundings*, which is the temperature at which water vapour condenses out. Remember, questions which are specific and in which you have shown obvious invested effort will be better received by the community.